# How to export and Sync a React Sandbox from CodeSandbox to Github repository?

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I have created a React project in CodeSandbox but I am not able to export, even after several tries. Getting the below error again and again.

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now , and here is what I did :
**1- make some changes on my code
2- try to change the name to a another name**
and Voila !!